# change border colors of dotchart in R

Tags: r, colors

```
chart_data=c(305,450,320,460,330,480,380,520)
names(chart_data)=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
dotchart(chart_data,color=c("pink","lightblue"),lcolor="lightgrey",
         pch=c("X","Y"),labels=names(chart_data),cex=1.2,
         xlab="Number",main="Year 2016-2017")
```

I made a dotchart like this. I tried to change many colors in this chart, but I couldn't find how to change the color of border, main, xlabs.

Could you let me know how to change colors? or is there no way to change those?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`?title` explains what you want (`col.main`, `col.lab`). You can use `bg` for the color and `col` for the border.  Here is your example:

```
chart_data=c(305,450,320,460,330,480,380,520)
names(chart_data)=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

dotchart(chart_data, lcolor="lightgrey",
     pch=23,labels=names(chart_data),cex=1.2,
     xlab="Number",main="Year 2016-2017", col.main=3, col.lab = 3, col = 3, bg = c("pink","lightblue"))
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I think I explained wrongly.

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of "table border"? and "gradation numbers"?